# Selecting Specific columns in Pandas data frame Using iloc

Tags: pandas, multiple-columns

0 income limit rating cards age education student married ethnicity balance female male

Hello I am trying to select all rows and the columns starting from "income" to "male" but skipping the "rating" column. Is there a way to point this out using iloc[] documentation??

Any help is welcome. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

if the text you have provided is the column names, this is a reasonably robust way to do it:

```
columns = list(df.columns)
idx_start = columns.index("income")
idx_end = columns.index("male")

cols = [col for col in columns[idx_start:idx_end+1] if col != "rating"]

df = df[cols]
```